# DVTAssertions: ASSERTION FAILURE (Command CompileStoryboard failed with a nonzero exit code)

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, xcode15

Just Updated MacOS and XCode and then tried to Build App. 
Now it is throwing Error: `Command CompileStoryboard failed with a nonzero exit code`

And after debug got following:

```html
[MT] DVTAssertions: ASSERTION FAILURE in IDEInterfaceBuilder/AutolayoutFoundation/Model/Constraints/IBLayoutConstraint.m:1141
Details:  We only understand width/height, not 0x3
Object:   <IBLayoutConstraint: 0x600001772c80>
Method:   -absoluteGeometricDescriptionInCoordinateSpaceOfView:userInterfaceLayoutDirection:ofItem:attribute:
Thread:   <_NSMainThread: 0x600002e780c0>{number = 1, name = main}
Hints:
```

**I already tried following steps:**

Deleted Derived Data,
Restarted Xcode and Mac, Cleaned build folder and then re-build it again, Reinstall cocoapods etc...

What can I do to fix this?

Any Help would be highly appreciable.